# Are the two properties of a vector (norm and angle w.r.t another vector) indpendent of each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Consider a random variable $a$ and constant vector $b$ drawn from $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\theta$ be the angle between the two vectors.
I am interested in finding expectation of $\mathbb{E}[||a||^2\sin^2\theta]$.
Is it correct to assume that the norm "$||a||$" and the sine of angle "$\sin\theta$" are independent of each other?

Intuitively, I think they should be independent because knowledge of one does not tell anything about the other.

Another intuition I am thinking of that might justify it is using probabilistic graphical models. We can consider a causal graph of a vector $a$, its norm $||a||$ and the angle $\theta$ w.r.t $b$, such that vector $a$ is a common cause that leads to the norm and the angle. So using the common cause analysis for the graphical model, the norm and angle must be at least conditionally independent.

Is my intuition in the right direction? Is there a more rigorous mathematical way of proving this?

Comment: The answer surely depends on the distribution of $a$.

Comment: Depending on the distribution of $a$, they could be independent or not.

Comment: What about conditional independence given $a$? The "common cause" argument in the "bayes ball algorithm" shows that the norm and the phase are independent if conditioned on the r.v. itself. Would that be a correct assessment?

Answer (score 0):

In general, they are not independent. Consider $b=(1,0)$ and $P(a=(1,0))=P(a=(0,2))=1/2$. Then obviously The angle is $0$ iff $\Vert a\Vert=1$.